How to parse a resume with few shot method using the specified models from HuggingFace and Langchain?
Model selection confusion and some errors while trying to parse a resume with the following codes

Trying to do a few shot prompting with a google flan t5 base model
While Doing so I am getting an error
ERROR:Service.service:Error parsing resume: "'ContactInformation'"
exception as "detail": "Failed to parse the file: An error occurred in parsed_resume: \"'ContactInformation'\""

The code is given below
from typing import List, Optional, Union, Any, re
import json



class ContactInformation(BaseModel):
    Name: Optional[str] = None
    Email: Optional[str] = None
    Contact: Optional[str] = None
    Links: Optional[List[str]] = None



class Experience(BaseModel):
    title: Optional[str] = None
    company: Optional[str] = None
    duration: Optional[str] = None


class Education(BaseModel):
    course: Optional[str] = None
    branch: Optional[str] = None
    institute: Optional[str] = None


class Projects(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    description: Optional[str] = None
    link: Optional[str] = None

class OutputFormat(BaseModel):
    ContactInformation: Optional[Any] = None
    AboutMe: Optional[Any] = None
    Experiences: Optional[List[Any]] = None
    Educations: Optional[List[Any]] = None
    Skills: Optional[List[Any]] = None
    Certificates: Optional[List[Any]] = None
    Projects: Optional[List[Any]] = None
    Achievements: Optional[List[Any]] = None
    Volunteer: Optional[List[Any]] = None


    def __init__(self, model_name=model_1, fine_tune_model_path: str = None):
        # Initialize LLM service with specified model


        if fine_tune_model_path:
            # Load fine-tuned model from local directory
            self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(fine_tune_model_path)
            self.model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(fine_tune_model_path)
        else:
            # Load base model
            self.llm_service = HuggingFaceHub(
                repo_id="google/flan-t5-base",
                huggingfacehub_api_token=huggingface_api_key,
                model_kwargs={
                    "temperature": 0.5,
                    "max_new_tokens": 200
                }  # Model parameters for consistent output
            )
    def parsed_resume(self, resume_txt: str):
        df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Sarthak\PycharmProjects\JobAxle\Service\data\for_model_resume_dataset.csv")
        print(df['prompt'][0])
        examples = [
            {'prompt':df['prompt'][0], "completion":df['completion'][0]},
            {'prompt': df['prompt'][1], "completion": df['completion'][1]}
        ]
        print('Examples:',examples[0])
        example_formatter_template = """
        {prompt}
        {completion}\n
        """
        example_prompt = PromptTemplate(
            input_variables=["prompt", "completion"],
            template=example_formatter_template,
        )
        parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=OutputFormat)
        few_shot_prompt_template = FewShotPromptTemplate(
            examples=examples,
            example_prompt=example_prompt,
            suffix="""
                Parse the given resume text, ensuring the output in JSON format:
        
                Resume:
                {resume}
        
                {format_instructions}
        
                Output as JSON below:
                completion:""",
            input_variables=["resume"],
            example_separator="\n",
            partial_variables={"format_instructions": parser.get_format_instructions()}
        )
        print("Few-Shot Prompt Template with Examples and JSON Instructions:\n", few_shot_prompt_template)

        prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
            input_variables=['resume'],
            template=Prompt_2
        )
        # print(few_shot_prompt_template)
        # Initialize the LLM chain
        chain = LLMChain(
            llm=self.llm_service,
            prompt=few_shot_prompt_template,
            verbose=True
        )
        print("Chain:", chain)
        print(resume_txt)
        try:
            response = chain.invoke({'resume': resume_txt}, verbose=True)
            print(response)
            logger.info('Model Response: %s', response)
            print("Type of Response:",type(response))
            # Invoke the chain and get a response
            response_json = self.process_response(response)
            parsed_json = self.structure_response(response_json)
            return OutputFormat(**parsed_json)  # Return as OutputFormat object

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Error parsing resume: %s", e)
            raise Exception(f"An error occurred in parsed_resume: {e}")

    def process_response(self, response_text: str) -> Dict:
        """Process LLM response into JSON format."""
        response_json = json.dumps(response_text).strip()

        # Remove extraneous characters
        if response_json.startswith("```json"):
            response_json = response_json[len("```json"):].strip()
        if response_json.endswith("```"):
            response_json = response_json[:-len("```")].strip()

        response_json = remove_trailing_commas(response_json)

        try:

            return json.loads(response_json)
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            logger.error("JSON decoding error: %s. Response text: %s", e, response_json)
            raise ValueError("Failed to parse response as valid JSON")

    def structure_response(self, parsed_json: Dict) -> Dict:
        """
        Structure response JSON to match the OutputFormat schema, ensuring lists for 'Experiences' and 'Educations'.
        """
        # Ensure ContactInformation, Experiences, and Educations are present in the expected structure
        parsed_json["ContactInformation"] = parsed_json.get("ContactInformation", {})
        if isinstance(parsed_json.get("Experiences"), dict):
            parsed_json["Experiences"] = [parsed_json["Experiences"]]
        else:
            parsed_json["Experiences"] = parsed_json.get("Experiences", [])

        if isinstance(parsed_json.get("Educations"), dict):
            parsed_json["Educations"] = [parsed_json["Educations"]]
        else:
            parsed_json["Educations"] = parsed_json.get("Educations", [])

        parsed_json["Projects"] = parsed_json.get("Projects", [])

        return parsed_json

The df contains prompt, completion feature with resume_text as a prompt and json output as completion.
Or Is there any Alternative to doing the task on a low-end specs laptop? I am in need of help because I can't access big parameter models. anybody??

Possible reason 1:
The LLM sometime does not produce consistent output. It might be possible that the key "ContactInformation" might not be present in the output generated by the model. So first do the dubugging and check the output of LLM directly.
Try this parsed_json.get("ContactInformation", {})
In case if the key is not present then it will add empty dict.
Possible reason 2:
It might be possible that the output generated by LLM is not even JSON. In that case it wont be able to use the get method on the JOSN.
